# Find the largest subset of it which form a sequence

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I came across this problem during an interview forum.,

Given an int array which might contain duplicates, find the largest subset of it which form a sequence. 
Eg. {1,6,10,4,7,9,5}
then ans is 4,5,6,7
Sorting is an obvious solution. Can this be done in O(n) time.

My take on the problem is that this cannot be done O(n) time & the reason is that if we could do this in O(n) time we could do sorting in O(n) time also ( without knowing the upper bound).
As a random array can contain all the elements in sequence but in random order.

Does this sound a plausible explanation ? your thoughts.

Comment: cannot think of any possible solution which can actually do it in O(n) time...

Comment: Well, in real life programming, you actually know an upper bound for integers. Hence, you could use bucket sort here, given enough memory. However, for arbitrary integers (mathematical integers) you are correct.

Comment: cannot think of - doesn't mean it's impossible.

Comment: Finding upper bound is also O(n), so combining it with bucket sort would give you O(n) - so teretically it is possible (just damn impractical for most applications).

Comment: I wonder if you could do something with a sufficiently large bit vector.  If the upper bound were only 31 and I walked through the unsorted sequence setting each corresponding bit in my vector (a single word in this thought experiment, that that's O(n) ... walking though the resulting bit vector is also O(n) (counting teach string of consecutively set bits, storing the starting offset and replacing that each time we find a new maximum therein.  That's also O(n).  2*O(n)simplifies to O(n).

Comment: Your reduction isn't correct, since it needs to solve the *generic* sort problem. For example, I claim that reversing an array cannot be O(n), since the reverse procedure is a correct sorting algorithm if the input is sorted in reverse order. Therefore given that input, it solves the sorting problem. Therefore via this reduction, the reverse procedure cannot be solved in O(n). This proof is obviously flawed for the simple fact that reverse can be solved in O(n). The problem is that I reduced it to a non-generic sorting problem.

Comment: @davin , I think you are taking me wrong here , my argument is very generic here. I am not talking about a specific input in particular.
 In your example reverse is just the order of sorting right ? How is it possible to sort in O(n) without using counting or bucket sort.

Comment: @vinay, it isn't generic, because let's assume you can solve this problem in O(n). You claim that now you can sort in O(n). So what do you do if the input has no consecutive numbers (which by the way is easy to create with *any* input by doubling)? How do you sort? Where's the reduction? You can only solve the sorting problem when you add extra assumptions about the input (that the numbers are consecutive and form a sequence). My example shows that when you add assumptions about the input, you lose generality.

Comment: I am trying to make my point by contradiction that if we are able to sort the above problem, we will have a O(n)sort , which is not possible , hence above problem cannot be solved in O(n).

Comment: And like I said, that argument is flawed, because you wouldn't have an O(n) sort, you would have an O(n) sequence-sort, which as mentioned isn't a contradiction because it can be bucket-sorted in O(n).

Comment: The reason bucket sorting in O(n) doesn't contradict the fact that sorting requires omega(nlogn) is because it *assumes something about the input*, namely that all the input will be bounded. Well, you're assuming your input is a sequence, and since it has n elements it must also be bounded. Therefore you're making the same assumptions, and so solving that problem in O(n) is **not** a contradiction.

Comment: so can the above prob be solved in O(n) time ? it would be great if you can provide some hint, been scratching my head for a long time over this one.

Comment: I don't know if it can or not, I'm just pointing out that your proof saying that it can't is invalid.

Comment: Suppose the array is given already sorted into ascending order.  @Vinay claims that it is then possible to solve the sequence problem in O(n) time.  How?  For example, if the input is (20 30 35 40 47 60 70 80 85 95 100), the longest sequence is 20,40,60,80,100 rather than 30,35,40 or 60,70,80.

Comment: @jwpat7: how are 20,40,60,80 and the other sequences you mentioned valid answers at all.  The OP said "sequences" and gave an example implying *contiguous* sequences (i.e. those monotonically increasing adjacent values by unit increment).  How are you inferring this other set of semantics for "sequence."

Comment: Written and tested in scala: https://github.com/sauravsahu02/practice-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/google/problems/FindLargestSubset.scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it can be solved in O(n) if you assume you have enough memory to allocate an uninitialized array of a size equal to the largest value, and that allocation can be done in constant time.  The trick is to use a lazy array, which gives you the ability to create a set of items in linear time with a membership test in constant time.

Phase 1: Go through each item and add it to the lazy array.

Phase 2: Go through each undeleted item, and delete all contiguous items.

In phase 2, you determine the range and remember it if it is the largest so far.  Items can be deleted in constant time using a doubly-linked list.

Here is some incredibly kludgy code that demonstrates the idea:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  static const int n = 8;
  int values[n] = {1,6,10,4,7,9,5,5};
  int index[n];
  int lists[n];
  int prev[n];
  int next_existing[n]; // 
  int prev_existing[n];
  int index_size = 0;
  int n_lists = 0;

  // Find largest value
  int max_value = 0;
  for (int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
    int v=values[i];
    if (v>max_value) max_value=v;
  }

  // Allocate a lazy array
  int *lazy = (int *)malloc((max_value+1)*sizeof(int));

  // Set items in the lazy array and build the lists of indices for
  // items with a particular value.
  for (int i=0; i!=n; ++i) {
    next_existing[i] = i+1;
    prev_existing[i] = i-1;
    int v = values[i];
    int l = lazy[v];
    if (l>=0 && l<index_size && index[l]==v) {
      // already there, add it to the list
      prev[n_lists] = lists[l];
      lists[l] = n_lists++;
    }
    else {
      // not there -- create a new list
      l = index_size;
      lazy[v] = l;
      index[l] = v;
      ++index_size;
      prev[n_lists] = -1;
      lists[l] = n_lists++;
    }
  }
  // Go through each contiguous range of values and delete them, determining
  // what the range is.
  int max_count = 0;
  int max_begin = -1;
  int max_end = -1;
  int i = 0;
  while (i<n) {
    // Start by searching backwards for a value that isn't in the lazy array
    int dir = -1;
    int v_mid = values[i];
    int v = v_mid;
    int begin = -1;
    for (;;) {
      int l = lazy[v];
      if (l<0 || l>=index_size || index[l]!=v) {
        // Value not in the lazy array
        if (dir==1) {
          // Hit the end
          if (v-begin>max_count) {
            max_count = v-begin;
            max_begin = begin;
            max_end = v;
          }
          break;
        }
        // Hit the beginning
        begin = v+1;
        dir = 1;
        v = v_mid+1;
      }
      else {
        // Remove all the items with value v
        int k = lists[l];
        while (k>=0) {
          if (k!=i) {
            next_existing[prev_existing[l]] = next_existing[l];
            prev_existing[next_existing[l]] = prev_existing[l];
          }
          k = prev[k];
        }

        v += dir;
      }
    }
    // Go to the next existing item
    i = next_existing[i];
  }

  // Print the largest range
  for (int i=max_begin; i!=max_end; ++i) {
    if (i!=max_begin) fprintf(stderr,",");
    fprintf(stderr,"%d",i);
  }
  fprintf(stderr,"\n");

  free(lazy);
}
```

Comment: I agree: with O(N) space available, the search can be done in O(N) time.  One O(N) pass through the original array to set the appropriate parts of the second array; one O(N) pass through the second array finding contiguous sequences, and keeping track of the longest so far.  At worst, there's another O(N) pass through the original array to find the minimum and maximum values, and hence determine the amount of auxilliary space needed.  And two or three consecutive O(N) passes leaves you with an O(N) computation.

Comment: The code shown above does not work.  Given the input n=11 and values[] = {20, 30, 35, 40, 47, 60, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100}, the posted code prints `20`.  It should instead print `20,40,60,80,100`.

Comment: @jwpat7: not really; it was designed for the contiguous numbers case, not finding arbitrary patterns).  In any case, 35 and 35 and 47 break up the 20, 40, 60 pattern.

Comment: The stated problem is to find the largest subset of of a set which forms a sequence.  The largest subset of {20, 30, 35, 40, 47, 60, 70, 80, 85, 95, 100} that forms a sequence is {20,40,60,80,100}.  The stated problem does not contain the word contiguous, and it does not say or imply that the numbers of the found sequence are to be consecutive integers.  The numbers of an arithmetic sequence need not be successive integers, but merely separated by a constant interval.

Comment: @jwpat7: Actually the program didn't say that it was an arithmetic sequence either, just a sequence.  The problem was underspecified, but I assumed that a sequence of consecutive integers was wanted because that was the answer given.  The sequence 1,4,7,10 would be an equally long arithmetic progression.

Comment: @Bhoot: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are ways to do it. The algorithm is the one you already describe, but just use a O(n) sorting algorithm. As such exist for certain inputs (Bucket Sort, Radix Sort) this works (this also goes hand in hand with your argumentation why it should not work).

Vaughn Cato suggested implementation is working like this (its working like a bucket sort with the lazy array working as buckets-on-demand).

Comment: O(n) sorting just works if you make assumptions about your input. There was no such assumption mentioned, so this probably does not work (unless, as this was an interview question and the correct answer would be "What assumptions can I make about the input").

Answer (score 1):

As shown by M. Ben-Or in *Lower bounds for algebraic computation trees*, Proc. 15th ACM Sympos. Theory Comput., pp. 80-86. 1983 cited by J. Erickson in pdf *[Finding Longest Arithmetic Progressions](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/pdf/arith.pdf)*, this problem cannot be solved in less than O(n log n) time (even if the input is already sorted into order) when using an algebraic decision tree model of computation.

Earlier, I posted the following example in a comment to illustrate that sorting the numbers does not provide an easy answer to the question:  Suppose the array is given already sorted into ascending order.  For example, let it be (20 30 35 40 47 60 70 80 85 95 100).  The longest sequence found in any subsequence of the input is 20,40,60,80,100 rather than 30,35,40 or 60,70,80.

Regarding whether an O(n) algebraic decision tree solution to this problem would provide an O(n) algebraic decision tree  sorting method:  As others have pointed out, a solution to this subsequence problem for a given multiset does not provide a solution to a sorting problem for that multiset.  As an example, consider set {2,4,6,x,y,z}. The subsequence solver will give you the result (2,4,6) whenever x,y,z are large numbers not in arithmetic sequence, and it will tell you nothing about the order of x,y,z.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? populate a hash-table so each value stores the start of the range seen so far for that number, except for the head element that stores the end of the range. O(n) time, O(n) space. A tentative Python implementation (you could do it with one traversal keeping some state variables, but this way seems more clear):

```
def longest_subset(xs):
    table = {}
    for x in xs:
        start = table.get(x-1, x) 
        end = table.get(x+1, x)
        if x+1 in table:
            table[end] = start
        if x-1 in table:
            table[start] = end
        table[x] = (start if x-1 in table else end)

    start, end = max(table.items(), key=lambda pair: pair[1]-pair[0])
    return list(range(start, end+1))

print(longest_subset([1, 6, 10, 4, 7, 9, 5])) 
# [4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a un-optimized O(n) implementation, maybe you will find it useful:

```
hash_tb={}
A=[1,6,10,4,7,9,5]

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if not hash_tb.has_key(A[i]):
        hash_tb[A[i]]=A[i]
max_sq=[];cur_seq=[]
for i in range(0,max(A)):
    if hash_tb.has_key(i):
        cur_seq.append(i)
    else:
        if len(cur_seq)>len(max_sq):
            max_sq=cur_seq
        cur_seq=[]
print max_sq
```