# Tracking number of entries in a row

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a bunch of contests a user can enter.  At any time there are about 10 active contests.  Every hour a new contest goes up and the oldest contest ends.  I want to track how many contests in a row a user competes in.  The only problem is that a user can enter contests out of order, but should still get credit as long as they compete in each contest before it ends.

I have worked on a few possible solutions, but each one seems to have terrible edge cases that are very difficult to detect.  Am I missing something or is this just a pretty hard problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically I am keeping track of the last contest the user participated in by updating the user record when each contest ends.  I then check if this contest matches the previously ended contest.  If it does, I increment their contestStreak counter.  If it doesn't, I reset the counter to 1.  This seems like the best way to do it and I can't believe I didn't realize this before.

Comment: What if the contests 1..10 are completed in order 1,2,3, 5,6? I think your heuristic will come up with 2, not 3.

Comment: I think this is taken care of by calculating when the contest ends. Also, I'm only worried about their current streak, not the longest streak.  So, 2 would be the correct answer after contest 6 ended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [longest increasing subsequence of a given sequence](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence) (O(n^2)). There are also O(n) and O(n log n) methods.

You might also take a look at this question: [Find the largest subset of it which form a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7683077/509840).